# Mocking in Spock framework

Tags: java, testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I tried to write test in Spock, but I have some problems.
Code will tell more... My tests looks like:

```
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    private MyService myService
    private MyDAO myDAO

    def setup() {
        myDAO = Mock(MyDAO)
        myService = new MyServiceImpl(myDAO)
    }

    def "Should get something"() {
        given:
        def user = Mock(User)
        def date = now()
        myDAO.getUsersSomethingFromDate(_ as User, _ as LocalDate) >> [ Mock(Something) ]

        when:
        myService.getUsersSomethingFromDate(user, date)

        then:
        1 * myDAO.getUsersSomethingFromDate(_ as User, _ as LocalDate)
    }
}
```

`MyDAO` is an `interface`.


I also tried different `setup` method:

```
    def setup() {
        myDAO = Mock(MyDAO) {
            getUsersSomethingFromDate(_ as User, _ as LocalDate) >> [ Mock(Something) ]
        }
        myService = new MyServiceImpl(myDAO)
    }
```

Despite I declared that method `getUsersSomethingFromDate` should return `[ Mock(Something) ]`, it returns `null`. In the next service method run I received `NullPointerException`, because returned 'null' instead of list of mocked instance.
The question is why mocked object with declared value to return still returns `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in combining of mocking with invocation count checking, because mock is not called then.

You can rewrite your combined test in this way to have it working:

```
def "Should get something"() {
        given:
        def user = Mock(User)
        def date = now()

        when:
        myService.getUsersSomethingFromDate(user, date)

        then:
        1 * myDAO.getUsersSomethingFromDate(_ as User, _ as LocalDate) >> [ Mock(Something) ]
}
```

See http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing

Comment: Checked. It works.In some parts Spock is not so intuitive... :)
Wired think is Spock allows to use `Mock(class) { something() >> "something" }` and the mock will return "something", but if we use `1 * something` it will return `null` if return is not specified in `then:` block.